# OnClientClick doesn't fire on first postback but will on second click

Tags: c#, gridview, postback, onclientclick, rowdeleting

Okay I have a gridview that allows users to delete a row, when the use clicks the delete link button the postback occurs. I get the index of the row that the button fires on which then calls a stored procedure that gets a count. But before the row is deleted a confirmation will display. The problem is the user has to click the Delete link button twice before the confirmation dialog box appears. Thank you in advance for your help code is below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="updtCompGrdVw" runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 DataKeyNames = "GUID"
                OnRowCancelingEdit="updtCompGrdVw_RowCancelingEdit" 
                OnRowEditing="updtCompGrdVw_RowEditing"
                OnRowUpdating="updtCompGrdVw_RowUpdating" 
                OnRowDeleting="updtCompGrdVw_RowDeleting"
 <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle Wrap="False" />
     <Columns>
   <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" HeaderText="Delete" CausesValidation="false">
             <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" />
           <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" VerticalAlign="Top" Width="40px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small"/>
              </asp:CommandField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void updtCompGrdVw_RowDeleting(Object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
            DataKey dtKey = updtCompGrdVw.DataKeys[index];
            string DKpif_id = dtKey.Values["GUID"].ToString();// +", " + dtKey.Values["itmID"].ToString(); 
            GridViewRow Row = updtCompGrdVw.Rows[index];
            conn.Close(); 
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("StoreProcedureName", conn);
            cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd3.Parameters.Add("@GUID", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            cmd3.Parameters["@GUID"].Value = DKpif_id;
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd3;
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                Session["CntctCount"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ContactsCount"].ToString();

                    (Row.Cells[Row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls[0] as LinkButton).OnClientClick = "if (!confirm('There are (" + Session["CntctCount"].ToString() + ") contacts associated with this company!, Are you sure you want to Delete this company?')) { return false; }";

                    ds.Clear();
                conn.Close();
            }
 }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OnClientClick event needs to be already wired up and the javascript available at the time when the user is clicking the delete button - in Page_Load, for instance.  [This link (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) may help you with the concept of page lifecycle, and [this link (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx) will help explain how to register your script.